# Archer T2U Nano won’t work no matter what

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, tp-link

I tried fixing dkms package `rtl8812au` from aircrack-ng and also another guy, but both failed. However, aircrack-ng’s provided one installs, but it shows a rigorously troublesome message and shows “No networks” in the menu.

And typing iwconfig, it looks like this

```
�7E��1   unassociated  ESSID:""  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency=2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=0/100  Signal level=0 dBm  Noise level=0 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

Typing lsusb, it looks like this

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 18f8:0f99 [Maxxter] Optical gaming mouse
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 09da:faa8 A4Tech Co., Ltd. USB Device 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0c45:64ab Microdia Integrated Camera
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 2357:011e TP-Link 802.11ac WLAN Adapter 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Typing "sudo dkms status", it looks like this,

```
8812au, 5.6.4.2_35491.20191025, 5.11.0-27-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au, 5.3.4: added
virtualbox, 6.1.22, 5.11.0-27-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the result of these terminal commands: `lsusb` and also: `sudo dkms status` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 Okay, I am getting my hands into it

Comment: @chili555 I have made the changes, kindly review

Comment: @chili555 Hey, thank you so much for letting me know about lsusb command, I figured out that my chipset was different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the wrong driver 'rtl8812au' where my needed driver was for 'rtl8811au'.

I have installed the new driver from [this](https://github.com/morrownr/8821au-20210708) repository. Now it works perfectly.

Comment: Your device is supported by the other driver  but there was some code that messed up the interface name

Comment: Furthermore, I just installed the correct driver and didn't even bother the older one, it is now up and running. So far so good!

Comment: how did you found that the driver you really needed?

Comment: @LucasVenturella I just looked up my adapter specification. There was written what I should use.